# Localization (via proj4) with multiple points. Datum transformations from state plane to local grid with user defined points

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, proj, proj4js, state-plane

I'm using [proj4](https://proj.org/usage/quickstart.html),
And I'm wondering what the best course of action is to convert from state plane to a local grid system.  I have files of these points from a .loc filetype that the user specifies.

```
<record id="Point 1" >
<value name="Lat" value="redacted"></value>
<value name="Lon" value="redacted"></value>
<value name="Ellipsoid_Elv" value="20.1497127691777"></value>
<value name="Local_X" value="redacted"></value>
<value name="Local_Y" value="redacted"></value>
<value name="Local_Z" value="152.2231851663858"></value>
<value name="HRMS" value="0.019685"></value>
<value name="VRMS" value="0.03937"></value>
<value name="Use_Horizontal" value="No"></value>
<value name="Use_Vertical" value="No"></value>
<value name="Description" value="1050"></value>
</record>
...
```

Now, I believe I can do a projection from state plane to a local grid system if I make my own "proj" or "wkt" string with proj.  What I am unsure about is how to factor in multiple points.

Is it an average of all the values and convert to that or is there some other kind of formula or something I am missing?